# Right direction of containment in MVP?

Tags: gwt, mvp

I've checked out a few different examples on MVP pattern and I found various implementations of it. Its not clear to me though which one should contain the other: the view or the presenter?

As the name suggests it:

```
public MyPresenter(){
   display = new MyView(this);
}
```

or as my sane logic(and a [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) page about MVP)

```
public MyView(){
   presenter = new MyPresenter(this);
}
```

or should I use something completly different approach creating these objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DOM is one of the most costly thing in browsers, so constructing widgets is costly in GWT. On the contrary, presenters are generally cheap, so they can be trashed and reconstructed at will.

That's why I'd recommend as a rule of thumb to try to reuse your views (make them singletons, or cache them for a few minutes) across many presenters.

This means your (short-lived) presenter should reference your (long-lived) view.

I'm a strong believer in dependency injection, so I wouldn't instantiate one from within another. This greatly helps in managing the components' lifetime, each one independently ofthe other.
So you'd inject your view into your presenter: create the presenter, pick the view (either create it or get it from your *cache*) and give it to your presenter. Then you'll destroy the presenter and keep the view around to be reused the next time you need it (with another presenter).

Comment: +1 For pointing out the costly things in the browsers. With this in mind I think I'll able to structure my project even better. I'm only starting GWT and DI is something I have to learn too (I only know about the design pattern but none of the frameworks) I will check out gin/guice then.

Answer (score 2):

One of the main reasons to use the MVP pattern is to isolate your logic in the Presenter so it can be unit tested.

If you do this:

```
public MyPresenter(){
   display = new MyView(this);
}
```

You will not be able to unit test your presenter without extending GWTTestCase, which is slow.
So I much prefer:

```
 public MyPresenter(MyViewInterface view){
     this.view = view;
 }
```

Where MyView implements MyViewInterface. The interface can be plugged with the real MyView implementation, or a test implementation that does not require firing up the GWT context for testing.